# Use of "had" in a sentence

Tags: tense, sentence-structure, past-perfect

> The earliest copyist engraver who had worked after Mantegna's pen
>   drawing had simply copied the lines that Mantegna made with his pen.

Mantegna made his drawing before it was copied. Then why is *had* used with the copyist and not with Mantegna in the above sentence?

Answer (score 0):

Had can be used in sentences, meaning past tense.

For E.g:

The earliest copyist engraver who had worked after Mantegna's pen drawing had simply copied the lines that Mantegna made with his pen.

The meaning of this sentence, tells us, when he did it. We can verify that this was done in past tense. Therefore, this is possible that he could've done his drawing before it was copied. He must've either done an outline of the sketch, copied it, then traced it by using Mantegna's pen.

Comment: The earliest copyist engraver who worked after Mantegna's pen drawing simply copied the lines that Mantegna had made with his pen. where the meaning of this sentence differs from the sentence I quoted above.

Comment: It is not past tense. had copied and had worked are past perfect tenses.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite for explaining the meaning of **after**.
The earliest copyist engraver who **had worked** in the style of Mantegna drawing **had simply copied** the lines that Mantegna *made* with his pen. They both precede the lines he **made** with his pen.

***VERB TENSE: "had worked" and "had copied" in the past perfect precede the verb made in the simple past.*** This is correct usage for that sequence of tenses.

"work after" here something specific in art and printing. to paint or draw "after" another work means to paint or draw in the style of that work. So, ***"after" here is not in time***. It's ***in the style of***. Now, the tenses are right.

Definition from an Auction House

Pablo Picasso. **After.** The auction house believes that the work was made by another artist, based on an original work by the named artist.

[auction.net](https://auctionet.com/en/help/175-attribution)